# TypeError using isin

Tags: python, pandas

I try to run the following code.

```
path="path"
df=pd.read_csv(path, header=0, delimiter=',',dtype=str)
df=df.loc[~df["x"].isin(df["y"]),:]
```

It yields the following error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

After a bit of investigation I found out that the dtype is in fact an object. Could this be causing the error ?
Is there a way to fix this without having to itterate over 7 columns 3 million rows to fix the datatype ?

The data looks like:

```
x         y          z
DE120     UK354     4506 
UK354     AT235     9783 
FE560     DK645     4652 
IT456     NL978     7831
```

I want to exclude all obsevations where x is also in y. (z is just 1 of the 5 other columns that is otherwise completely irrelevant to this story, just want you to know it's there)

```
x         y          z
DE120     UK354     4506 
FE560     DK645     4652 
IT456     NL978     7831
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the dtype of the columns you are trying to fit ? Are `x` and `y` numbers, strings, lists ?

Comment: Each item in x and y is a combination of numbers and letters. But even if it was completely numerical, should my call to read as string not override its most efficient type and just end up as string ?

Comment: My bad, I had missed the `dtype=str` part. I tried with a sample dataframe containing string, and `df[df['x'].isin(df['y'])]` works just fine, so I would say there is a problem "with" (or about) your data. Are there any missing values?

Comment: Can you show the sample dataset

Comment: As for your merging issue, there is a problem with your syntax : you can only merge one dataframe to another, i.e. two dataframes at a time, (unless you use `pandas.concat()`) : `df = df_left.merge(df_right, on=['x'], how='left')`.

Comment: My silly sample dataset, which probably has nothing to do with Peter's data: `foo = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['1233', '2345', 'aaa123bbb'], 'y': ['aaa123bbb', '1234', 'bbb124aaa']})`.

Comment: @Archeo Fits the general parameters of the data. Added a more exact version to the question.

Comment: @Peter - I use your solution and it works nice. `df=df.loc[~df["x"].isin(df["y"]),:]` or simplify `df[~df["x"].isin(df["y"])]`. Still same error?

Comment: Or maybe is necessary remove `NaN`s - `df=df[~df["x"].isin(df["y"].dropna())]`. Can you check it with your real data?

Comment: I agree with @jezrael: the code should work, and the error probably comes from `NaN` values, which are being treated as `float` (hence the error message). You can consider using either `df['y'].dropna()` or, more generally, `df.fillna('')` so as to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Peter - one idea - what is your version of pandas? (`print (pd.show_versions())`) last is `0.20.2`. Maybe some bug in older version of pandas

Comment: Error started popping up after an update. Guess old one ignored my NaN's. fillna solved the problem. I just fill it up with something that I can recognize as a filler and change back after the slice. Thanks for the help.